# How does apply lag command in lists?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, matrix, apply

Let's say that I have the following list

```
 Total<-list(matrix(1:64, nrow = 8), matrix(65:128, nrow = 8), matrix(1:64, nrow = 8), matrix(65:128, nrow = 8),)
```

I want to create a list of lists that contains the lagged variables of my original variables. Let me explain better my problem using only one matrix of my list.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
mat <- Total[[1]]
p <- 3 # number of lags
m <- 5 # values to include
mat_df <- as.data.frame(mat)
# Step 1: Lagged by values by mapping over 1:p
mat_lag <- map(1:p, ~ mutate_all(mat_df, lag, .x)) %>% 
  # Step 2: Drop rows with missing
  map(drop_na) %>% 
  # Step 3: Now slice. Only m values starting from the last row are kept
  map(~ slice(.x, (nrow(.x) - m + 1):nrow(.x)))
# Step 4: Convert to list of matrices
mat_lag %>% 
  map(as.matrix)
```

I want to use this code with all my matrices in the list but i do want to use the `for` command. Could I use an `apply`command?

Comment: You could put all of your code in a function, perhaps call it `my_fun`...then you can iterate through your list of matrices with `lapply(Total, my_fun)`...sounds like that would give you what you need without a `for` loop...